# Как в golang вызвать методы наследуемого типа map?

Tags: golang, map

Добрый день!
Я новичок в Go и столкнулся с проблемой.
Есть код:

```
package main

import (
            "fmt"
)

type MyMap map[int]struct{}

func (iw *MyMap) Add(item int) {
    *iw[item] = struct{}{}
}

func main() {
    iw := make(map[int]struct{})
    iw.Add(1)
    iw.Add(2)
    iw.Add(3)
    iw.Add(2)
    fmt.Println(iw)
}
```

При запуске он выдает ошибу:

```
invalid operation: iw[item] (type *MyMap does not support indexing)
```

Как заставить работать этот метод без приведения типов аля:

```
func (iw *MyMap) Add(item int) {
    t := map[int]struct{}(*iw)
    t[item] = struct{}{}
    *iw = MyMap(t)
}
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Приоритет разыменования меньше всего, надо поставить скобки.

```
func (iw *MyMap) Add(item int) {
//v   v Вот тут вот
  (*iw)[item] = struct{}{}
}
```

А вообще, map это ссылочный тип, для него не надо методы с указателями делать, отсюда проблема и начала расти =)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type MyMap map[int]struct{}

func (iw MyMap) Add(item int) {
    iw[item] = struct{}{}
}

func main() {
    iw := make(MyMap)
    iw.Add(1)
    iw.Add(2)
    iw.Add(3)
    iw.Add(2)
    fmt.Println(iw)
}
```